# 'langchain' is not a package

Tags: python, langchain, chatgpt-api

Running into this error while trying to run a basic tutorial script for langchain:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain.llms'; 'langchain' is not a package
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0.9)
text = "What is a popular recipe using coconut milk?"
print(llm(text))
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that one of my project files was named `langchain.py`. Renaming the file fixed this issue, otherwise it was importing the file instead of the actual library.

Found the answer here originally: https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/issues/2079

Answer (score 1):

My **langchain version is 0.0.339**, I import OpenAI by this script.

```
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI
```

You can also run this code in your terminal: `pip show langchain`. If the langchain is not present on your library, just run `pip install langchain`. You should also check version python, the requirement python version is `≥ 3.8. 1 and <4.0.` Quick installation [Installation Langchain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr2jp.png)

I usually run langchian with python 3.11, my steps are as follows:

1. `conda create --name my_env python=3.11`
2. `conda activate my_env`
3. `pip install langchain`
4. `pip show langchain`